# How to make a resizeable (from conner) layout like in 3d max main window

Tags: wpf, resize, grid, controls, gridsplitter

I have WPF prototype application which includes 1-4 other controls (WebBrowser control) like on picture
A need to resize a control (with facebook) taking it's conner and reducing size until the center of a window. If the size of this control would be less then "minSize" then it should be hidden\closed. Other layouts should fill an empty area.
[image]

I don't know from which controls should I start my experiments. No one does the right work.
I tried Grid, but it's impossible to take cell's conner to resize webBrowser control. 
GridSplitter works just for two panels and doesn't let me take cell's conner.
Some developers say about custom control creating...

Comment: Not exactly your requirement, but did you looked at http://avalondock.codeplex.com? It offers a great windows floating/docking/ model

Comment: Looked at that. AvaloDock gives like VS2010 controls' behavior using splitters but doesn't solve my problem at all. Thanks.